flask_socket not working on live server (aws ec2 instance) but work localy
i am try to connect socket with angular app with flask_socket library but when i try to connect with live server which deploy on aws ec2 its give error code of 404 but its working if i run flask server localy
app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app,cors_allowed_origins='*')
CORS(app,  resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})

@socketio.on('connect')
def handle_connect():
   print('Client connected')

@socketio.on('message')
def handle_message(message):
   print('Received message:', message)
   emit('response', 'Server received: ' + message)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   socketio.run(app,debug=True,host='0.0.0.0',port=8000)


also i configure nginx
  location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
          

location /socket.io {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/socket.io;


    }               }





First, I would suggest you fix the indentation of your nginx file and then make sure the blocks are correctly formatted. It appears as if the second location block is inside the first, which is wrong.
Second, you say you get a 404 error, but you don't say on which URL.

@MiguelGrinberg all routes are working with this url but socket dont work here is URL "https://imgstockhub.in/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=O-6fGy8"  and please elaborate about nginix you say coz i am new for this

ok i understand formatting is fine i just put fragment so...

@MiguelGrinberg
